# Using webhook to disguise as an user but it somtimes stops working

Tags: python, discord

So here's the problem, I wrote a command called sudo for my discord bot( It was use to disguise as another user and send messages). I was using a webhook(with the name of the user I tag and the avatar of the user I tag) to send the message then delete the webhook, so that it looks like that the user I tag has sent the message. At first it works perfectly,  but then it'll somtimes just delete the message( the command ) and does nothing else. There's no error been raised. I've tried to figure out what happend but the only thing I found is that: It seems to stop working from the line where I declared webhook.

```
@client.command()
async def sudo(ctx, member: discord.Member, message):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if message:
        webhook = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name=member.name)
        await webhook.send(
            str(message), username=member.display_name, avatar_url=member.avatar_url)
        webhooks = await ctx.channel.webhooks()
        for webhook in webhooks:
                await webhook.delete()
```